# Spring Boot REST endpoint not returning JSON

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
case class X(s: String)

@RequestMapping(path = Array("/tagReads"), produces = Array("application/json"))
def tagReads(@RequestParam(value = "tagId") tagId:String): X = {
  val response = X("Hello")
  println(response)
  response
}
```

`curl -H "Accept: application/json localhost:8080/tagReads?tagId="1234"` results in exactly what I would expect being println-ed in the spring boot app, but the response I get is {}.

If I change the return to just "Hello" and the type to String then I get "Hello" returned when I curl.

I don't like that I'm getting empty JSON the rest of the time. I am using `spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.6-RELEASE`and this is all wrapped in an `@RestController` annotated class.

There is nothing useful logged to the Spring Boot application console.

I'm stuck - all the examples I've seen suggest this should 'just work' - so any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried registering the [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala)?

Comment: Share Controller from Spring Boot

Comment: @Igor That was it - if you write it as an answer I'll accept!

Comment: @user2682459 Glad it helped solving the issue you had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to support Scala Case Classes serialization, try to add the [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) as your dependency and register the Scala module with the Jackson `ObjectMapper` e.g.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```